# LWC @wire works only if page is refreshed, not when I use navigation arrows

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, refreshapex

I have a checkbox that updates another field in another page.
I got a problem with @wire. To get refreshed data I need to refresh the whole page manually pressing F5. If I switch to another navigation using chrome left and right arrow, it does not show the correct value in checkbox.
How can I retrieve info without reloading page?

Here is HTML Code:

```html
<lightning-input type='checkbox' checked={interestListChecked} onchange={interestList}></lightning-input>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```js
import updateInterestList from '@salesforce/apex/PurchaseController.updateInterestList';
import getInterestList from '@salesforce/apex/PurchaseController.getInterestList';

@track interestListChecked = false;

interestList(event){
    console.log('teste->> '+event.target.checked);
    this.interestListChecked = event.target.checked;
    console.log('this.interestListChecked '+this.interestListChecked);
    if(this.interestListChecked == false){
        this.sendEmail = false;
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id="checkout"]').disabled = false;
    } else {
        this.sendEmail = true;
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id="checkout"]').disabled = true;
    } 
    console.log('purchaseId: ' + this.purchaseId);

    updateInterestList({purchaseId: this.purchaseId, interestListCheckBox: this.interestListChecked}).then((response)=>{
        console.log('RESPONSE: ' +JSON.stringify(response));
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error->> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}

interestListChecked;

@wire(getInterestList, { purchaseId: '$purchaseId' })
getInterestList({data, error}){
    console.log('testewe - purchaseId->> ' +this.purchaseId);
    if (data) {
        console.log('Data: ' +JSON.stringify(data));
        this.record = data;
        this.interestListChecked = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' +JSON.stringify(error));
        this.error = error;
        this.record = undefined;
    }
}
```

Here is my Apex Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
   public static string updateInterestList(Id purchaseId, Boolean interestListCheckBox){
       try {
           Purchase__c purchase = [ Select InterestList__c from Purchase__c where Id = :purchaseId LIMIT 1];
           purchase.InterestList__c = interestListCheckBox; 
           update purchase;
           return 'Ok';
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return e.getMessage() + ' - '+ e.getStackTraceString();
       }
   }

   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static Boolean getInterestList(Id purchaseId){
       try {
           Boolean interestCheckbox;
           Purchase__c purchase = [ Select InterestList__c from Purchase__c where Id = :purchaseId LIMIT 1];
           interestCheckbox = purchase.InterestList__c;
           return interestCheckbox;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

@wire methods fire when their input parameters change. In your case, you have a parameter of `{ purchaseId: '$purchaseId' }`. I do not see this value being changed in your code, therefore the @wire method wont fire.

If your updateInterestList Apex method is doing something that updates your record, you should call `refreshApex()` instead to refresh the wire

Comment: I pasted my apex code for you to see.

Comment: I noticed you have 2 variables for interestListChecked. That might cause you to have problems.